# How to make lombok annotation @NotNull work in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, lombok

For some reason lombok @NotNull annotation does not work in my maven project in IntelliJ IDEA.

I have a maven lombok dependency on version 1.16.16.
[image]

Here is my import statements.

[image]

As you see other lombok dependencies work fine.
I discovered that @NotNull annotation has retention policy CLASS and other annotations (@Data, @NoArgsConstructor, etc) have retention policy SOURCE. Any ideas how to fix the issue?

Comment: Have you already installed the [Lombok Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317-lombok-plugin)?

Comment: refresh/update maven project, enable intellij idea annotation processing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The annotation is @NonNull, with an 'n'